# After a discussion on the functional equation $f(x)=f^2(\frac{x}{ \sqrt 2})$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In a test the question was posed to find $f(x)$ where given a relation $f(x)=f^2(\frac{x}{ \sqrt 2})$ . And also the fact that $f(1)=2.$ All my friends got this by inspection that $f(x)=2^{x^2}$. But I need a rigorous proof of it .

I tried changing variables ,comparing coefficients  and lot of other stuff , Its too tedious and a lot of it does not work . So is there a simple and elegant method of this ?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, without any hypothesis of continuity, one can make other solutions.

To see one, let $A=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) =\{a+b\sqrt{2}, a,b\in  \mathbb{Q}\}$. We have for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ that $x\in A$ is equivalent to $\displaystyle \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\in A$. Hence if we define the function $g$ by $g(x)=2^{x^2}$ for $x\in A$ (hence as $1\in A$, we have $g(1)=2$), and $g(x)=0$ if $x\not \in A$, we have a new solution. (And we can take also $g(x)=1$ if $x\not \in A$.)

Answer (score 0):

Write 
$$f(x)=f^2\left(\frac{x}{ \sqrt 2}\right)=f\left(\frac{x}{ \sqrt 2}\right)f\left(\frac{x}{ \sqrt 2}\right)$$

in table

$$\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{1}{ \sqrt 2}\right)&=&\sqrt{2}\\
%
f(1)&=f\left(\frac{1}{ \sqrt 2}\right)f\left(\frac{1}{ \sqrt 2}\right)&=2\\
%
f(\sqrt{2})&=f\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{ \sqrt 2}\right)f\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{ \sqrt 2}\right)=f(1)f(1)=&4\\
%
f(2)&=f\left(\frac{2}{ \sqrt 2}\right)f\left(\frac{2}{ \sqrt 2}\right)=
f\left({ \sqrt 2}\right)f\left({ \sqrt 2}\right)=&16\\
\end{align}$$
and conclude.

Note, the first value obtained using second.